# I need to take off <p> from data using react

Tags: html, reactjs

I receive data from database like this :

```
description:<p>my name is ....</p>
```

I put this in a table, all I need is to put the text only, how can I remove the `<p></p>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove your html tags by using regex

```
const htmlRemoveRegex = /(<([^>]+)>)/gi;
const newString = description.replace(htmlRemoveRegex, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly replace the `<p>` and `</p>` tags only using the `String.prototype.replace()` JS string method, available as `.replace(string, replacement)` on any string in JavaScript. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```js
const description = '<p>my name is ....</p>';
const newDescription = description.replace('<p>', '').replace('</p>','');
console.log(newDescription);
```